# How to read XML file on port 80 using HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, xml, port, httphandler

How do I read a XML file sent by the client at port 80 using HttpHandler in ASP.NET?

Comment: I created a TcpClient object in the ProcessRequest method of the handler and was planning to parse through the POST message. I did not realize that the object created a server instance inside the handler and ran into port deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume the client use the `POST method`.

```
<httpHandler>
  <add path="1.ashx" verb="post" type="" />
</httpHandler>
```

the Httphandler code :

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var stream = context.Request.InputStream;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var xml= sr.ReadToEnd();  //json format       
        XmlDocument.Load(xml)
    }
}
```

the client code using js.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "1.ashx",
        data: { xml:"<xml/>" }
    });
</script>
```